# Can I add WMS layers to a MapGuide 6.5 map?

Tags: wms, mapguide

A bit of a long shot, but I recall a few years ago seeing a WMS 'connector' for MapGuide 6.5 that allowed you to add WMS layers to a MapGuide 6.5 map.  I can't seem to find it anywhere now, and am pretty sure it's impossible given the technology, but thought I would ask.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Why not migrate your MapGuide 6.5 to MapGuide Open Source 2.2 ?

Comment: Why do not use MapGuide Open Source [OSGEO](http://mapguide.osgeo.org/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using the liteview you can accomplish.

[MG 6.5 forum question](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-MapGuide/About-WmsAdmin/m-p/1212821/highlight/true#M1237)

Comment: Thanks Brad. It does appear that it is not possible unless liteview is used. Marking your question as the answer.